# Qual a diferença entre split(" ") e split()

Tags: python-3.x

Estou manipulando strings e me deparei com essa questão. Eu achava que a semântica das formas de usar era a mesma, mas vi que não e isso me deixou confuso.

No caso achava que com o uso de `split(" ")` todos os espaço da string original seriam removidos e eu teria algo como:

> ['07', '10', '11', '20', '30', '44', '34\n']

Mas o que eu obtive na saída foi:

```
palavra = "     07 10 11 20 30 44 34\n"

splt = palavra.split(" ")

print(splt)
```

**retorno:**

> ['', '', '', '', '', '07', '10', '11', '20', '30', '44', '34\n']

E com o uso de `split()` saiu bem mais próximo do que eu esperava.

```
palavra = "     07 10 11 20 30 44 34\n"

splt = palavra.split()

print(splt)
```

**retorno:**

> ['07', '10', '11', '20', '30', '44', '34']

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se você der o comando abaixo

```
print(help(palavra.split))
```

verá o resultado abaixo

```
Help on built-in function split:

split(sep=None, maxsplit=-1) method of builtins.str instance
    Return a list of the words in the string, using sep as the delimiter string.

    sep
      The delimiter according which to split the string.
      None (the default value) means split according to any whitespace,
      and discard empty strings from the result.
    maxsplit
      Maximum number of splits to do.
      -1 (the default value) means no limit.
```

Veja então que `" "` (espaço) tem o resultado diferente de `None`

None, ou seja o uso de `.split()` descarta strings vazias.

Espero ter ajudado

Comment: Desculpa, n sei se entendi certo, então o `split(" ")` só vai ser removido de fato quando estiver entre outros valores, no meu caso os números. O `split()` vai remover todos estando entre outros valores ou não, isso?

Comment: @Shinforinpola  `split(" ")` irá separar a string nos espaços e manter tudo o que encontrou (no seu exemplo, encontrou "vazios"), enquanto `split()` fará a mesma coisa a princípio e então descartará esses "vazios".